# How to disable messages from syslogd for my own user?

Tags: linux, non-root-user, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I am using a Centos Linux OS with ssh tools. I get these messages every minute.

```
Message from syslogd@rakhsh4 at May  6 17:48:34 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.

Message from syslogd@rakhsh4 at May  6 17:48:34 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: CPU:6 (10:9:1) MC4_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|CECC]: 0xdc02400021080a13

Message from syslogd@rakhsh4 at May  6 17:48:34 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: Error Addr: 0x0000000654f3f030

Message from syslogd@rakhsh4 at May  6 17:48:34 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: MC4 Error (node 1): DRAM ECC error detected on the NB.

Message from syslogd@rakhsh4 at May  6 17:48:34 ...
 kernel:[Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, mem/io: MEM, mem-tx: RD, part-proc: RES (no timeout)
```

I really don't care about those messages. Mainly because it's not my business to care about the system. 
I don't have access to the root privileges. So the solutions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1184832/disable-rsyslog-remote-server-s-console-messages) which requires changing and commenting some stuff in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` will not be an option for me.

So, my question is, how can I suppress these messages for my own user without having the root privileges?

Comment: Best ting to do is a polite request to the system administrator to make the change to `etc/rsyslog.conf` with reason for the change being given that it is interfering with your productivity.

Answer (score 5):

The quick and dirty workaround is to comment out this line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
# Everybody gets emergency messages
#*.emerg                    :omusrmsg:*
```

At least it worked for my CentOS 7 box.

You could write them to a specific file to preserve these messages and make them easy to find. Something like this:

```
*.emerg                    /var/log/EMERG
```

Yes. That setting as a default is super intrusive. On a syslog server, any server in the environment throwing emerg messages can bork the console.

Restart the rsyslog daemon for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Generally, the EMERG priority *should be* limited to messages that constitute the kind of emergency where you *want* everyone working on the system to be interrupted so they can stop whatever they're doing and make sure their work is saved before the admin decides that the proper response to the emergency is to issue a shutdown.